# prove this function: $f(x,y) = y^2/(x-x^2) $ with $x$ in $(0,1)$ is convex

Tags: calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

I want to show this function is convex. I know that this can be done by computing its hessian matrix. But this's gonna be tedious, that's why I would like to have a workaround.

Thanks in advance

Comment: more tedious than writing this question and waiting around for someone to come up with an alternative for you? Just compute the Hessian, it will take you like 5 minutes max.

Comment: If you think it tedious I would strongly encourage you to do it that way for practice. This is an elementary example.

Comment: You could show it directly by the definition: for $\lambda\in[0,1]$

\begin{align}
f(\lambda(x,y)+(1-\lambda)(x',y')) &= \frac{(\lambda y + (1-\lambda)y')^2}{(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) x')(1-(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x'))}\\ &\leqslant \frac{\lambda y^2}{x(1-x)}+\frac{(1-\lambda)y'^2}{x'(1-x')}\\ &= \lambda f(x,y) + (1-\lambda)f(x', y').
\end{align}

I think you will agree that computing the Hessian is a more practical approach, however.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{2y}{x-x^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = \frac{2}{x-x^2} = \frac{2}{x(1-x)} > 0 ~\forall x \in \left(0,1\right)$$
$\therefore$ for $x \in \left(0,1\right) f$ is convex.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y^2 \cdot \frac{2x-1}{x^2(1-x)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = y^2 \cdot \frac{-6x^2+6x-2}{x^3(1-x)^3}=y^2 \cdot \frac{-6\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}}{x^3(1-x)^3}>0~\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$$
$\therefore$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is convex.

$\therefore f$ is convex $\forall x \in \left(0,1\right), y \in \mathbb{R}$.